# permissions error related to Stripping when Creating RPM on CentOS from source code

Tags: centos, rpm, stripping

When building an RPM from existing source code, I'm getting the following error:

> /usr/bin/strip: unable to copy file
>   '/home/vagrant/temp/BUILDROOT/python3-3.4.3-1.el6.x86_64/usr/lib/libpython3.4m.a';
>   reason: Permission denied

When I look at the permissions for this file, it has no Write permission.

> -r-xr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant 12823866 May 14 17:33 libpython3.4m.a

I've tried setting the permission in the %files section:

`%attr(0644,root,root) /usr/lib/libpython3.4m.a`

But this has no effect.

When does the stripping process occur, and how can I fix the file so it can be stripped, before the stripping operation occurs?

Comment: strip'd be somewhere in the compile phase. depending on how things are being built, this might be something you have to fix at the underlying makefile/build instructions level, and not in the rpm.

Comment: The stripping happens wherever in the build process it is being run. Probably in `%build` if that is par of the build itself or during packaging at the end (if this is part of the `-debug` rpm creation). In either case you need to fix the permissions in `%build` or `%install`. The `%files` section just controls what the permissions are on disk once the rpm is installed.

Answer (score 1):

The configure script creates a Makefile. In that Makefile is the following:

```
# Shared libraries must be installed with executable mode on some systems;
# rather than figuring out exactly which, we always give them executable mode.
# Also, making them read-only seems to be a good idea...
INSTALL_SHARED= ${INSTALL} -m 555
```

I'm no automake expert, so there may be some option to adjust this. However, instead I do this in my %install section of the spec file

```
%install
sed -i 's/INSTALL_SHARED= ${INSTALL} -m 555/INSTALL_SHARED= ${INSTALL} -m 755'/ $RPM_BUILD_DIR/Python-%{version}/Makefile
make install DESTDIR=$RPM_BUILD_ROOT
```

Additionally, since I was building python I also needed to turn off the rpm brp-python-bytecompile part of the post install. I found this on the fedora mailing list and the credit goes to David Malcom @ RedHat. Here is the [original thread](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/devel/2010-April/135368.html) - you can put it at the top of your spec file:

```
%global __os_install_post %(echo '%{__os_install_post}' | sed -e 's!/usr/lib[^[:space:]]*/brp-python-bytecompile[[:space:]].*$!!g')
```